# Can I call Deferred<>.await() many times?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am newbie about coroutines and I have a simple question.
Can I call await() many times to get result value?
E.g.

```kotlin
class Test: CoroutineScope {

val my_value = async { "Hello World!" }


suspend fun f1() {
    println(my_value.await())
}

suspend fun f2() {
    println(my_value.await())
}
```

I suppose second call "await()" will immediately return computed value. It's right?
Tnx

Answer (score 12):

You can call `Deferred.await()` as many times as you want/need. The result is simply returned or the exception is thrown again.